# WKWebView scrolls to the top after keyboard opens

Tags: ios, swiftui, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView app, and in the url it loads it's got editables (inputs) to type in. But in the ios app when you tap an input that's at the bottom of the page, it opens the keyboard as expected, scrolls down on the page so you can see the input as expected, then it scrolls back to the top after half a second. So I tried it in the browser, but it didn't scroll back up after a split second. Does anyone know why this is happening only in my ios app?

Here's my code:

ContentView.swift:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        WebView(url: URL(string: "https://www.mywebsitenamethatiwontshare.com")!)
    }
 }

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

WebView.swift:

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {

    var url: URL

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you might be causing a refresh of the view in your updateUIView function. Try removing the webView.load inside and try

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {

    var url: URL

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
       // DO NOTHING
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Suyash Medhavi, sadly it didn't work for me. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure what it's bug on app, can you tried on other website? Because I check it on stackoverflow and haven't this problem

Comment: Yeah, I just tried loading stackoverflow like you said and it doens't have the same problem. I'm betting it's a problem with my website then. Thanks @sergio_veliz!